# Find a div with certain class and add some HTML after and before it (with PHP!)

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, dom, wordpress-theming

I have the following problem - How to find a div with class "test" and add "`</div>`" **before** it and "`<div class="sth">`" **after** it.
More detail example:

```
<!-- The original code -->
<div class="parent">
   ...here we can have some more content...
   <div class="test"></div>
</div>

<!-- The thing that I want to achieve -->
<div class="parent">
...here we can have some more content...
</div>

<div class="test"></div>

<div class="sth">
</div>
```

I tried with javascript/jQuery but with no success, because it is generated in DOM.
So I decided to do it with something that will work on it before to show the content.

Any ideas how to accomplishe that?

(The content will be generated by Wordpress posts, if that would help you...)

p.s. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: If its generated in DOM then how you want it to be render again in PHP?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone. I decided to do it with copy the whole content as plain html text and than with jQuery find and replace the things I want while loading a simple gif loader.

It's not the best and fastest solution, but for now works like a charm :-).

Thanks again.

Comment: Thank them by giving them an up-vote, they spent time and effort trying to help you. Choose the ones that would have been a suitable solution to your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use your code here jsu before the end of the body tag, `</body>`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
$( ".test" ).insertAfter( ".parent" );
});
```

That wrapper will cause your code to be executed when the DOM is fully constructed. If, for some reason, you want your code to execute immediately instead of waiting for the DOM ready event, then you can use this wrapper method instead:

```
    (function($) {
        // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
        // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
$( ".test" ).insertAfter( ".parent" );
    })(jQuery);
```

Ref:http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

http://jsfiddle.net/itsazzad/wW4Pv/1/

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) , get the `<div>`'s that you want and then append the other code after. I think that would be the simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried with `jQuery` with no success. But maybe you want to try this successful approach:

```
$('.test').wrap('<div class="sth"></div>');
```

Don't forget to execute it when the DOM is ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('.test').wrap('<div class="sth"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
var page = document.documentElement.InnerHTML;
document.documentElement.InnerHTML = page.replace("<div class=\"test\">","</div><div class=\"test\"><div class=\"sth\">");
```